# Does the Manager's manager need to know disputes in teams?

Tags: management, manager, conflict, people-management, conflict-resolution

I was reading about conflict resolution and I read a good approach, if a situation is considered as a conflict that wont resolve by itself, is to start with the manager calling an informal and private discussion with the team members that are having the conflict. The meeting should be taken seriously of course and the good will from the team members to resolve it apparent.
But even though HR would not be involved, I read that the upper management would be informed. I suppose the manager's manager.
But why is that necessary?
First of all what if the upper management has a different idea on how to resolve it leaving the manager as a "liar" about informality.
Also wont it have big impact on the team members since they would not consider it something honest? Or even being stressed too much at an early stage?
What am point am I missing?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: i read it in the book Conflict resolution at work for dummies

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: by liar I mean that an informal process was stated to the team members but upper management decided to make it formal overriding their direct manager. Not a real case, trying to understand all the scenarios

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: it does not explicitly say that. It mentions in general that there should be an email invitation which should be clear who is involved. And offers an example email that states at some pont: "Our department head has asked that I report the result of the meeting to her and I've agreed. I will not however be sharing anything other than if an agreement has been reached and any follow up needed." Hence I got confused on what is the usual practice

Comment: @smith You are ignoring this _much more important bit_ from the same chapter: "You know your workplace, and you know what's appropriate and not appropriate when it comes to written meeting requests."

Comment: @PhilipKendall: that is too vague and the warning right after it also seems to imply involvement of others. But I may be reading it the way

Comment: @PhilipKendall: you were right. Reading further it is clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But why is that necessary?

It isn't. The whole point of a chain of command is that you solve all the problems you can and only if you cannot, you ask for assistance from above.

If you as a manager directly involve *your* manager at the first sight of a problem, then what is your justification for having your job in the first place?

You are supposed to solve this problem and only if you feel you cannot do that, should you involve your manager. That means you should at least try. I like the idea of an "an informal and private discussion". But have you *ever* had a "a informal and private discussion" with *your bosses boss present*? That's ridiculous. That is as formal as it gets short of a public comittee hearing.

The "informal and private discussion" is with *you* as a mediator, referee or commander, depending on how strictly organized your company is. That is the meaning of "private".

If you find you cannot handle interpersonal conflict in your department, you may want to ask for training or delegate to a trained professional in your organisation. Some companies have trained mediators or union representatives to help solve disputes between employees without a "boss" making a judgement call. Your boss is probably the wrong person anyway. The attribute of "being your boss" doesn't make them any better at doing this. Only more intimidating and formal and that is not how you resolve conflicts in the long term.

Comment: Great answer. I would supplement it by saying that in some cases if the dispute warranted it, and considering seniority, then you may inform your manager that you have resolved a team dispute. This would generally be done informally in a weekly catch-up type meeting. I would expect this at the team leader level, not at a unit, group or department head level. It would be as simple as 'I've dealt with an issue between two team members, it has been resolved and no work was impacted'. That way, if it blows up, there are no surprises if you need to call on your manager for help.